# С#. Не могу понять почему не работает ограничение where T : struct при работе с ValueType

Tags: c#, .net

```
[Fact]
public void Test()
{
    int data = 10;
    Convert(data);

    DateTime data2 = DateTime.Now;
    Convert(data2);

    Lang l = Lang.Eng; //Enum
    Convert(l);

    //???
    Convert(null);
}

public string Convert(ValueType data)
{
        Foo(data);
}

public static string Foo<T>(T val) where T : struct  //notnull
{
    //Do something..
}
```

Метод `Foo` должен принимать в себя `ValueType`, ну как я это понимаю (все числовые типы, `DateTime`, `bool`, `struct`).
Ограничение на generic функцию `where T : struct`

Я думал можно передать любой `ValueType` в такую функцию, но получил ошибку

Ошибка компиляции:
The type 'ValueType' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Foo(T)

также я смог передать null под ValueType. Я думал что для таких случаев нужно специально задавать Nullable значение.

Я так понимаю это особенность `C#8 с non-nullable` типами?
В документации есть ограничение notnull.
Я не до конца понял что это за ограничение и как мне задать ограничение для моего случая?

Comment: ValueType - это базовый абстрактный класс для типов-значений, НО то, что тип является "типом-значением", не говорит что он не может являться ссылочным и обязан быть структурой, но определяет поведение при определенных операциях над значениями этого типа, например, при передаче значений этого типа в качестве параметров. Так что C#8 тут ни причем и если хотите работать с ValueType, то и в ограничение дженерика ставьте именно ValueType, а не struct. И да, int? - не перестает быть ValueType, но может принимать значение null.

Comment: Спасибо за объяснение. Суть понял. Но вот ограничение ValueType не ставиться на generic функциию

Comment: CS0702 Constraint cannot be special class 'ValueType'

Comment: Что можете рассказать про notnull ограничение?

Comment: Мой вопрос не решен!!